# Choose one of Rav Kook's books

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, abraham-isaac-kook

Which of Rav Kook's books would be the one to learn if you want to see his learning style and methodology.
What I mean is, in which book does he most "show his work" so to speak.

Answer (score 5):

You probably will want to start with Orot. R Bezalel Naor recently came out with [a very nice English translation](http://a.co/5DENR0K) including an extensive historical introduction and notes.

However, be warned that this is a very difficult text to learn alone. The style is very poetic and there are many references to concepts which are not explicit in the text. I learned it with a specialist of R Kook and realized I would not have understood 10% on my own. Audio shiurim going through the text might be a worthwhile alternative.

Another book which helps get into R Kook's works is [The Essential Writings of Abraham Isaac Kook](http://a.co/ciFP220) by R Ben Zion Bokser which includes selections of various works incl. Orot of course.

Answer (score 3):

I second @mbloch's suggestion for Orot as a book that gives an excellent overview of Rav Kook's hashkafa over a range of topics that were important to him.

However, in terms of learning his learning style and methodology - I would suggest [Ein Ayah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_Ayah) (עין איה), which shows what went on in his head when he learned gemara. Sadly there's only on Brachot and Shabbat, but both provide a wealth of insight into Rav Kook's thought process, the way he broke down the gemara and analyzed various parts of it.

Note: Though it's a kind of commentary on the gemara - and not just the aggadic parts (it's regarded as a commentary on Ein Yaakov, but there are also non-aggadic sections if I remember correctly) - it's focused on the spiritual and hashkafic aspects and not the more technical halachic aspects.